# cURL error 7: Failed to connect to localhost port 4444: Connection refused

Tags: php, laravel, curl, post, guzzle

I have been trying to send a request post to my localhost using **guzzlehttp/guzzle v6.2.3**  but i keep getting the error shown in the title. I have tried to make the call using **Postman** and it works fine. I have been doing some searching and found that most people solve the issue by changing **localhost** to **127.0.0.1** or to the IPv4.. I have tried all of them but still getting the same error every time. Here is my code:

```
$client = new Client();
$res = $client>post('http://localhost:4444/api/abc/xyz',request(['x', 'y']));
echo $res->getStatusCode();
```

Please assist me resolving the problem.

Comment: What's listening on port 4444?

Comment: the port is correct, it points to the correct path(just to inform you that I have tried using postman and it works fine, I will add it to the question)

Comment: Most thing's I've found suggest that something is blocking outbound TCP connections from your server. Perhaps a firewall config?

Comment: I have actually disabled all the firewall configs just in case. but still facing the issue

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution. actually the issue is caused because i'm using homestead, so I can't use localhost as it will browse the VM localhost. I had to change the path to

> http://10.0.2.2/api/abc/xyz